# django - ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)

Tags: python, django, email, ssl, smtp

I'm trying to send an email in django, but I can't. I keep getting an SSLError (With the code below) or I get timed out (When I use port 465)

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_smtp_ssl.SSLEmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.office365.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config['EMAIL']
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config['PASSWORD']
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = config['EMAIL']
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_USE_STARTTLS = True
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You are using the port for SSL (587), but have set `EMAIL_USE_SSL` to `False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the configuration issues that are causing this error:

1. Your `EMAIL_BACKEND` is not correctly specified.
2. You are correctly using port `587` for the `EMAIL_PORT` but `EMAIL_USE_TLS` is `False`.
3. You can't set both `EMAIL_USE_TLS` and `EMAIL_USE_SSL` to `False`.

Corrections:

1. `EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"`
2. If you are setting `EMAIL_USE_SSL` to `False`:

   ```
   EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
   EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
   EMAIL_PORT = 587
   ```
3. If you are setting `EMAIL_USE_TLS` to `False`:

   ```
   EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
   EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
   EMAIL_PORT = 465
   ```

For further information, you can refer to Django's documentation on email sending [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/email/).